# How do I use 2-D arrays to determine whether or not something is a Magic Square? (requires much help, please)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, copy-constructor, deep-copy

*Before I ask my question, I want to make myself clear that **I am not expecting someone to do my lab for me.** I am seeking **genuine help to understand** my lab, I am using StackOverflow because it is consistent and helpful. **YES I have searched for answers to my question elsewhere.** I am trying my best to format a detailed "good" question.*

Okay this is a MagicSquare prgogram. Unlike others I have viewed online, the program we are writing is to determine whether or not a two-dimensional array is a Magic Square. After it determines whether or not it is, it will print the result. I am struggling in my class when it comes to writing a program. So if you could please help me out, I would appreciate it. (More specifics are commented within my code)

```
            public class MagicSquare {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int [] [] square3 = {{ 1, 6, 4}, {8, 2, 9} {5, 7, 3}}; // this is for the 3x3 matrix

        MagicSquare case1 = new MagicSquare( square3 );

        String table = case1.toString();

        System.out.println(table);

        // Do I stop here for the first array?

        int [] [] square4 = {{16, 3, 2, 13}, {5, 10, 11, 8}, {9, 6, 7, 12}, {4, 15, 14, 1}}

        //do something here for the rest of the second 2d array
```

The above is pre-written code, I understand that it is setting up what will be printed. Is the case1 necessary for doing this or could you use a loop instead?

```
        if(case1.isAmagicSq( ))
            System.out.println("...is a magic square..." );
        else
            System.out.println("...is not a magic square... " );

        //repeat for the 4x4 square
    }
```

This simply states whether or not it is a magic square.

```
}/* write the constructor nd two instance methods here */

    //1. Write a constructor to create a deep copy of the 2-D array
    //formal parameter. There should be a private instance field for
    //holding the deep copy of the input array
private int arrayCopy(int [] [] square3, square4){ 

    int [] = new int[square3.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < square3.length; i++)
            result[i] = square3[i];
    return result;

    int [] = new int[square4.length];
        for( int i = 0; i < square4.length; i++)
            result[i] = square4[i];
    return result;

}
```

Am I on the right track for writing a deep copy of the array? Would I use the variables above?

```
    //2. Write the toString method to return a String with a table 
    //containing the magic square



    //3. Determine if the 2d array is or is not a magic square
    //by using an instance method

    public static int count Elements( int [][] array){

        int result;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) result+=array[i].length;
            return result;
    }

    public static int[] rowI(int data[][], int i){

        if(i<data.length) 
            return data[i]; 
        else 
            return null;
    }
```

For the last one I have started to write something that (should) count across each row to see if they add up to what a MagicSquare is supposed to be. Obviously I'm not finished, but I didn't want to continue if I'm completely incorrect...

Comment: I didn't realize how long my question was. Also, I really just need a step by step approach to writing a program. I don't get much help in school, and I'm trying extremely hard to understand what I'm learning. So please don't get frustrated with me!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.
StackOverflow is not a tutorial service; the size of your question set is outside the SO scope.  What I feel you need is a little training in testing, and discipline in development.  Write a few lines at a time.  Stick in print statements to track the program flow and variable values.  Make sure those few lines work before you move ahead.  When you hit a specific problem, post here.  See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a deep copy of any sort to validate a magic square.  You should just pass the square to some method, and that will add up the numbers for each row and column.  Passing the object is done by reference, and since you are not modifying it, you shouldn't have to worry about any copy function.  This is the most critical part of the exercise, I would work on that first.

Everything you need to do should be in that method you defined:

```
public boolean isAmagicSq(){
    // do your checks here
}
```